# How to modify or delete a calendar event?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-calendar, smartphone

I am building an android application in java script which, among other things, creates events in the system calendar, modifies them or deletes them.
To create events in the calendar I use the following code, which works as expected.

```js
ad @#ßỉwjd+dify the above code to modify or delete an existing event from the system calendar?
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the structure of `android.intent` is written by bad programmers and it is always difficult to get a grip on it, even for talented and experienced programmers. The API are cumbersome and tangled, and the documentation is written by illiterates.

To modify an event use the same code by modifying the second line in this way

```js
[object Object]
```